# Vehicle Tracking System[java/Java EE]

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

I am interested in building a vehicle tracking system using GPRS. However, I have some questions for anyone who has done this before:

- Is GPRS the best technology to use? Any problems people are aware of?
- I am planning on using Java/Java EE  - is there any better technologies?
- If someone has built this before - do you have some examples of what to see for system requirements?
- What are some good web resources you've found working on this?
- Is there a step-by-step guide anywhere to getting started?

Comment: Your question is far to generic to be answered. What exactly are you trying to do ? Yes, there are difficulties in any technology. We wont be able (and probably dont want to) write requirements for you. Good luck !

Comment: Are you sure you mean GPRS and not GPS?

Comment: Yes I can't tell you if Java is good for your project unless you tell me what you are trying to do beyond "vehicle tracking"

Answer (score 2):

If you're just doing it for fun/personal use and Amateur Radio licenses are available where you are, look into APRS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a phone with a GPS receiver (internal or otherwise). External receivers are easier to use because they are addressed by an older Java JSR (http://www.jsr82.com/) and thus better supported in  Java ME.

On the client side (phone), you can write midlets in Java (see JaveME) to access the GPS location of the device and then use the phone's data connection (GPRS or 3G) to make a HTTP request to a server that will track the location of the device. The only alternate I see to GPRS/3G is SMS but that makes things more complicated on the server side (you will need access to an SMS gateway with an GSM operator).

For the APIs required to build Java midlets, register with Nokia - they have a developer site that offers all the information you need. Of course, if you use another type of phone Nokia's stuff is not of much help.

There are some existing solutions for the client side - google for TrekBuddy - that can probably be used for a proof-of-concept.

On the server side you can write a servlet that tracks a device by device id and records the coordinates as sent by the phone.

Answer (score 1):

> If someone has built this before - do you have some examples of what to see for system requirements?

Some of the questions are too generic to answer, but to specifically answer this one. Here is one example.

Generally the software components (and a hardware component) that you would need are:

1. **GPS tracking device** - Capable of reporting the location over internet (or SMS). XeXun TK102 compatible devices are common in under $100 category, but there are plenty of other options.
2. **Server and database** - for storing the location / history. Java EE stack is a good choice here.
3. **Map based reporting application** - For viewing and analysing the location data. Typically a desktop, mobile or a web application.

Here is one simple open-source Java EE / Spring based vehicle tracking server, database and web-based mobile map application (2-3 above). It uses TK102 compatible GPS/GPRS tracking device (1):

https://github.com/mstahv/tindratracker