# Vehicle tracking system/Jan08

Tags: java, gprs

we are developing cost effective vehicle tracking system,
 for my knowledge Using GPS to track vehicle costs more.
So we are looking to develop using GPRS system which costs less.

my doubt is can track the vehicle using only GPRS (not using GPS at all)
  is this possible .please correct if i am wrong if you any documentation or link it will be useful.

thanks in advance,
 Mahesh

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416708/vehicle-tracking-systemjava-j2ee

Comment: What are your research in terms of cost telling you? You get a retail GPS module for under $30 - so I guess for manufacturing it is much less. That is less cost than you would have to pay for a SIM card and the additional work service for buying cell tower information. BTW: how is that related to java and programming?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need an exact location you can use cell tower information and some external api to get the coordinates for each tower.
It's the same function that google uses in their mobile Maps application.

Example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/DeepCast.aspx